# How to disable thumbnails icon preview only for video files in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, video, icon

I hate my finder opening slow because of loading all those icons for video files. While I still want thumbnails for PDFs, documents, music, I don't want previews for video files because they're useless anyway (most of them are simply black but take time to load).

I managed to do it on previous OS X versions but on my Mountain Lion I can not locate /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Resources/Generators/ folder where I was able to delete generator for video files in the past.

How to turn video icons preview thumbnails off?

Answer (score 4):

The Mountain Lion default QuickLook generators can be found in the folder /System/Library/QuickLook/ .